# How to include and refer to a module-specific CSS file?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to insert a ngx-loading-bar ([link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-loading-bar)) into my angular2/4-app. I followed all the instructions given and the loading-bar actually seems to be there but the problem seems to be that the app can't find the loading-bar.css file. How do I refer to it?

styleUrls doesn't work. The file is on the same level/in the same folder as the app.ts

Thanks in advance.

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "a-contrainer",
    template: `<body>
    <ngx-loading-bar></ngx-loading-bar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </body>`,
    styleUrls: [`loading-bar.css`]
})
```

```css
/* Make clicks pass-through */
#loading-bar,
#loading-bar-spinner {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -moz-transition: 350ms linear all;
  -o-transition: 350ms linear all;
  transition: 350ms linear all;
}

#loading-bar .bar {
  -webkit-transition: width 350ms;
  -moz-transition: width 350ms;
  -o-transition: width 350ms;
  transition: width 350ms;

  background: #29d;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10002;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
}

/* Fancy blur effect */
#loading-bar .peg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 2px;
  opacity: .45;
  -moz-box-shadow: #29d 1px 0 6px 1px;
  -ms-box-shadow: #29d 1px 0 6px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #29d 1px 0 6px 1px;
  box-shadow: #29d 1px 0 6px 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#loading-bar-spinner {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10002;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;

  border:  solid 2px transparent;
  border-top-color:  #29d;
  border-left-color: #29d;
  border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:     loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation:      loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
  animation:         loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the styleUrls property, you need to specify a proper path in as the value.  My guess is that the problem is that the path to `loading-bar.css` is not correct.

Typically, this should be a path relative to the current file, so you probably want to add something like this:

```
styleUrls: [`./loading-bar.css`]
```

See [here for more information](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).